# How can I use DOS interrupts in 32-bit Windows assembly?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, dos

So I was writing assembly code in TASM. But now I want to migrate it to MASM and have it run on 32-bit Windows. Can I still keep the DOS interrupts or is there some other way to do it?

I want to ideally run this on Windows 10.

Comment: What would be important to know is if you intend to create true Win32 applications (console or GUI are supported), or whether you intend to just run 16-bit DOS programs on Windows 10. The answer to that question would dictate the course you would have to consider.

Comment: I want to create applications that can run in Windows without an emulator or DOSBOX.

Comment: Does that include the 16-bit NTVDM subsystem that emulates DOS/BIOS routines on 32-bit variants of the Windows OSes? If you don't wish to use that emulation layer provided by 32-bit Windows OSes then you'll be forced to get away from writing 16-bit programs (which means doing away with the DOS/BIOS calls you are accustomed to). There are many tutorials on the internet about writing assembler code for Win32 using MASM. Google is your friend.

Comment: Trivia - For 16 bit windows 3.1, there was a 32 bit WinMem interface to allow 32 bit programming without having to install Win32s, but the only compiler to fully support this was Watcom C / C++ 10, which made it popular until Win 95 took over. There are also 32 bit dos extenders (like Phar Lap TNT, used by early Microsoft compilers and some games). I don't know if this is supported in a dos console program for 32 bit versions of Windows. As mentioned, 16 bit interface was dropped on 64 bit versions of Windows.

Comment: Related: [16-bit Assembly on 64-bit Windows?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3620670)

Answer (score 2):

16 bit code from Windows 95 will still run on 32 bit windows at least until windows 7 (I don't have the software to try it on Windows 10).

However for 32 and 64 bit code, you have to start using the win32 api which use the less exciting "call" instruction instead of interrupts.

Comment: So 32 bit code generated using TASM won't work either?

Comment: @Ashara: If TASM can assemble 32bit code, then sure you can do anything with it.  You still have to port your code from the DOS `int 21h` system call API to the system call API for the system you want to run under.  It's not just a different ABI for the same API; it's a real change in what system calls are available.  You might want to port straight to 64bit, and not bother making a 32bit version as well.  IDK how similar Windows syscalls are between 32 and 64bit.

Comment: @PeterCordes : It is frowned upon by MS to make `syscalls` directly for compatibility reasons. The preferred mechanism is to make the calls indirectly through system DLLs like user32.dll, kernel32.dll, gdi32.dll, etc which comprise the Win32 API.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: That's what I actually meant.  Is that not how people normally talk about it?  Are the underlying system calls much different from win32 API the wrapper DLLs implement on top of them?  In Linux, for example, many libc functions are just thin wrappers around the syscall of the same name, usually providing some `EAGAIN` retrying or pthread handling, and setting `errno` on negative ret vals. (`open(2)`, `mmap(2)`, etc.  You'd talk about using the syscalls, but a "normal" program would actually call the glibc wrappers, the same as for non-syscall library functions like `strtod(3)`).

Comment: @PeterCordes In Windows over the past 20 years, Microsoft has altered the underlying system calls and created compatibility issues with some hand crafted ancient code. In some cases the underlying system calls changed substantially enough to cause issues. On Linux you can more or less get away with skipping GLIBC and doing the system calls directly because Linux seems to retain backwards compatibility.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Yup, Linus has maintained a strict policy of "never break userspace", so in theory ancient binaries with ancient glibc will work on modern Linux kernels.  Instead of changing a system call, they add a new syscall and turn the old one into a compatibility wrapper inside the kernel.  This happened a lot for i386, as Linux grew up and got 64bit versions of syscalls like `stat64`.  e.g. the current `mmap` glibc wrapper calls `#define __NR_mmap2 192` on i386, but just `__NR_mmap` on amd64.  See `/usr/include/asm/unistd_32.h`

Comment: @PeterCordes Windows never documented any sort of system call interface, so no effort whatsoever has been made to keep it compatible between versions. From the very beginning the Windows NT changed the system call numbers every for every significant update of the OS. Windows 95 used a completely different interface with completely different functions. Any Windows program that tries to call the kernel directly is fundamentally broken and always has been.

Comment: @RossRidge: I'd say "fundamentally not portable" rather than "broken".  I thought I made it clear I was talking about doing this as a looking-under-the-hood exercise for use only on your own desktop, not as a valid way to write production code.  Although if even a regular Windows Update patch could break your program, then that would make it less fun.  Thanks for confirming that the syscall numbers really are unstable in practice.  (And I assume some semantics change, too).

Comment: Hmm, actually I was probably thinking of a different comment thread where this came up.  The whole "only as a learning exercise" point wasn't present in this thread.  Oops.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: no, you can't. Under Win32/Win64, calling a DOS interrupt from a Windows program will crash your program with an "Invalid operation" message. Figure out what are you trying to do with DOS interrupts (console output? writing to files?), find corresponding Win32 API functions, and call them.

UPDATE: depends on what are you after. DOS interrupts are only available to DOS executables; Windows executables have to use Windows API. It's entirely possible to make Windows executables in assembly, MASM included, but you'd have to learn new techniques. Building DOS executables is supported in older versions of MASM, but that skillset is rather pointless in today's computing environment. For one thing, the DOS subsystem is slowly but surely going away from Windows - 64-bit versions of Windows don't have it anymore.

Comment: Not entirely true. On X86/WIn32 systems, NTVDM will execute many 16-bit DOS programs. Most (not all) of the DOS/BIOS interrupts are supported. Ones that aren't would generally compromise security.

Comment: MASM, which the OP is after, is not capable of generating DOS executables anymore.

Comment: Actually he didn't say which version of MASM. MASM 6.14/6.15 is more than capable of generating 16-bit code.

Comment: Good point. Still, the OP seems to be confused between "running on Windows" and "running Windows executables". Let me clarify.

Comment: On that point I agree. What is unclear is if his intent is to actually write Win32 applications. Which is why I downvoted the question.